# XSL-FO Place 3 tables side bij side

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am XSL-FO (fop apache) I want to place 3 tables side by side!
Tried al lot of thing but haven`t found the solution yet.
This is the important peace of my code :

```
<fo:table  table-layout="fixed" width="60mm" keep-together.within-page="always"  border-width="1pt" border-style="solid" border-color="black" >

                        <fo:table-column column-width="40mm"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="20mm"/>

                        <fo:table-body>

                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell text-indent="1mm">
                                <fo:block>test:</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>test</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>

                        </fo:table-body>

                    </fo:table>
```

Now I want to add 3 the same tables side by side. Can someone help?

Comment: Describe further what happens when one or more go over a page and what happens when one is longer than the others. Also, are the row heights all different  or the same?

Comment: Hello @KevinBrown 3 tables on half a page the height doesnt matter just want to know how to put them side bij side. all heights of the tables are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place each of the tables in absolutely positioned block-containers next to each other. Like this:

```
            <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" top="1in" left="0in" width="2.4in">
            <fo:table>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black">
                            <fo:block>I am Table 1</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black">
                            <fo:block>I am Table 1</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block-container>
        <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" top="1in" left="2.5in" width="2.4in">
            <fo:table>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black">
                            <fo:block>I am Table 2</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black">
                            <fo:block>I am Table 2</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block-container>
        <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" top="1in" left="5in" width="2.4in">
            <fo:table>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black">
                            <fo:block>I am Table 3</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black">
                            <fo:block>I am Table 3</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block-container>
```

Yields:

[image]

There are other ways but I do not think they are supported by FOP. If you were using RenderX you could use an rx:flow-section of 3 columns and put a table in each of the columns.

Comment: Great solution!